# Conditionals and regex doubts with grok filter in logstash

Tags: regex, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm taking my first steps with elastic-stack with a practical approach, trying to make it work with an appliacation in my enviroment. I'm having difficulties understanding from scratch how to write grok filters. I would like to have one like this one working, so from that one, I can work the rest of them.

I've taken some udemy courses, I'm reading this "Elastic Stack 6.0", I'm reading the documentation, but I can't find a way to make this work as intended.

So far, the only grok filter I'm using that actually works, is as simple as (/etc/logstash/config.d/beats.conf)

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { 'message' => "%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} % 
{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}"
    } 
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
  }
}
```

This is one of the log entries I'll need to work with, but there are many with different forms. I just need to have this one sorted out so I can adapt the filters to the rest.

2019-02-05 19:13:04,394 INFO  [qtp1286783232-574:http://localhost:8080/service/soap/AuthRequest] [name=admin@example.com;oip=172.16.1.69;ua=zclient/8.8.9_GA_3019;soapId=3bde7ed0;] SoapEngine - handler exception: authentication failed for [admin], invalid password

I'd like to have this info, only when there is a "soapId" and when the field next to "INFO" starts with "qtq":

```
date: 2019-02-05
time: 19:13:04,394
loglevel: INFO
identifier: qtp1286783232-574
soap: http://localhost:8080/service/soap/AuthRequest
Which could also end in things like "GetInfoRequest" or "NoOpRequest"
account: admin@example.com
oip: 172.16.1.69
client: zclient/8.8.9_GA_3019
soapid: 3bde7ed0
error: true (if either "invalid password" or "authentication failed" are found in the line)
```

If the conditions are not met, then I will apply other filters (which hopefully I will be able to write adapting this one as a base).

Comment: You can't have `false` if you have `invalid password` in the input. You can only match what is there in the string.

Comment: Try something like `%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} *\[(?<identifier>qtp[^\]\[:]*):(?<soap>[^\]\[]*)]\s*\[name=(?<accout>[^;]+);oip=(?<oip>[0-9.]+);ua=(?<client>[^;]+);soapId=(?<soapId>[^;]+);].*?(?:(?<error>authentication failed).*)?$`. You might need to double escape backslashes.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor! That worked at first attempt. I'm trying to fully understand it now following this guide https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE
I don't see the option to mark your comments as "answers", so I only upvoted them. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: See my explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `false` in the output if you have invalid password in the input. You can only match what is there in the string.

I think you may use

```
%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} *\[(?<identifier>qtp[^\]\[:]*):(?<soap>[^\]\[]*)]\s*\[name=(?<account>[^;]+);oip=(?<oip>[0-9.]+);ua=(?<client>[^;]+);soapId=(?<soapId>[^;]+);].*?(?:(?<error>authentication failed).*)?$
```

Here are the details of the added patterns:

- `*` - 0+ spaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?<identifier>qtp[^\]\[:]*)` - Named group "identifier": `qtp` and then 0+ chars other than `:`, `]` and `[`
- `:` - a colon
- `(?<soap>[^\]\[]*)` - Named group "soap": 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]\s*\[name=` - a `]`, then 0+ whitespaces and `[name=` substring
- `(?<account>[^;]+)` - Named group "account": 1+ chars other than `;`
- `;oip=` - a literal substring
- `(?<oip>[0-9.]+)` - Named group "oip": 1+ digits and/or dots
- `;ua=` - a literal substring
- `(?<client>[^;]+)` - Named group "client": 1+ chars other than `;`
- `;soapId=` - a literal substring
- `(?<soapId>[^;]+)` - Named group "soapId": 1+ chars other than `;`
- `;]` - a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:(?<error>authentication failed).*)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - Named group "error": `authentication failed` substring
  - `.*` - all the rest of the line
- `$` - end of input.